# Sum of paths III - Leetcode

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-tree

Given a target sum , we need to find the path count i.e total no of paths. Also it is given that , it is not necessary the path needs to start from the root node.

I came across a solution , for this question. I am also able to understand 85% of the solution.

Solution :

```
def pathCounter(node,currPath,_sum):
    if node is None:
        return 0
    path = []
    currPath.append(node.data)
    
    pathSum , pathCount = 0, 0
      
    #Unable to understand below for loop
    for i in range(len(currPath)-1,-1,-1):
        
        pathSum +=currPath[i]
        path.append(currPath[i])
        
        
        if pathSum==_sum:
            pathCount+=1
            #print(path)
            
    pathCount+= pathCounter(node.left,currPath,_sum)
    pathCount+= pathCounter(node.right,currPath,_sum)
    
    del currPath[-1]
    
    
    return pathCount
```

The issue I have is, I am unable to understand , why the for loop is set to iterate in reverse order and not in normal order ?

How does this affect the problem ?

Comment: I will be returning only the pathCount, commenting the path won't be an issue

Comment: Why then do you have the variable `path`?

Comment: I used it for debugging purpose. Also wanted to check if I can print the path.

Comment: Nope, if I replace the line of code with '"for i in range(len(currPath)): " it does not work

Comment: You're right. But the order of the accumulating sum is important. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that when you perform the loop in the forward direction, the `if` condition is going to check the sums that represent a *pre*fix of `currPath`, instead of a *post*fix.

As the recursion *appends* node values at the end of `currPath` it does not make sense to repeat the check of prefix sums (as that would already have been checked earlier on). The prefix sums would *always* include (the value of) the root node, while we cannot assume the root node must be included in a solution.

The purpose of the recursion is to *include* the newly visited node in all sum-checks, and since that new node is sitting at the end of `currPath`, the sum should accumulate from the end in a backwards direction.

For example:

Let's say there is a downward path in the tree with these values: 10 - 5 - 3 - 1, and that we need to find a sum of 8. Then in the first level of recursion, we visit 10, and in the next we visit 5. At this point we verify these sums:

```
* 5
* 5 + 10
```

Neither gives a match, so we recur deeper and visit 3. Now we check these sums:

```
* 3
* 3 + 5 => It's a match!
* 3 + 5 + 10
```

If at this stage we would have done a forward loop, we would have checked these sums:

```
* 10
* 10 + 5
* 10 + 5 + 3
```

None would match, and we would never have checked any sum that does *not* include the root.